# How to clear a custom option via REST product update

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, rest-api

I am using product repository save() (rest POST /V1/products) to create/update products.

With a single select attribute I can add an option, but can't see any way to clear the attribute option if it's already set.  Have tried sending 'null' and '' - doesn't add a new attribute, but also doesn't remove any existing ones either.

Here's a sample of the custom_options object within the product object.

```
 "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "color",
      "value": "98"
    }
```

If I do something like this, the value remains in the database.

```
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "color",
      "value": null
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that null works - I had some custom code which was returning a false value.

Confirmed that data is being removed from catalog_product_eav_int/varchar for single/multi select attributes.